# Зелёное выделения на фоне блока кода

Tags: python, интерфейс, pycharm

Использую PyCharm Pro. Есть несколько факторов которые появились и начали мешать при написании кода:

1. Подчеркивания зелёными волнами. Что же в этом коде не так? Почему функцию подчеркивает. Не пустая же.

[image: Красным виделил.]

2. Выделяет блок кода зеленым фоном. Что? Зачем.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S Прикрепляю ещё сюда, что пишет в подсказке, или же проблеме [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все выделения можно отключить. Первое - редактор не нашёл слово ilot в словаре и думает, что это может быть опечатка. На второй картинке - пичарм говорит, что в нём не настроено подключение к базе и не указан диалект SQL, поэтому недоступны некоторые дополнительные инструменты работы с SQL-кодом.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!!!

Comment: @Xander, напишите этот комментарий как ответ, чтобы я смог поставить галочку. Или подскажите как с комментария сделать не "полезный комментарий", а ответом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все выделения можно отключить.

Первое - редактор не нашёл слово ilot в словаре и думает, что это может быть опечатка.

На второй картинке - пичарм говорит, что в нём не настроено подключение к базе и не указан диалект SQL, поэтому недоступны некоторые дополнительные инструменты работы с SQL-кодом.

Comment: А как отключить, не подскажете?

Comment: В моей версии пичарма есть в правом нижнем углу маленькая иконка в виде головы в шляпе. Откроется окошко, в котором нужно сдвинуть ползунок на None (если вы хотите отключить проверки совсем). Если же нужно отключить только некоторые проверки, то надо в этом окошке нажать Configure Inspections. Тогда откроется другое окно, в котором можно поснимать галочки с тех проверок, которые вам не нужны.